# How to properly implement useQueries in react-query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, react-query

I'm using `react-query` to make two separate queries in the same React component. I originally tried using two `useQuery` hooks:

```
export default function Component() {
  const [barData, setBarData] = useState();
  const [lineData, setLineData] = useState();
  const { error: errorBar, isLoading: loadingBar } = useData(
    "barQuery",
    "BAR_TEST_SINGLE",
    setBarData
  );
  const { error: errorLine, isLoading: loadingLine } = useData(
    "lineQuery",
    "LINE_TEST",
    setLineData
  );

  const isLoading = loadingLine && loadingBar;
  const error = errorLine && errorBar;


  if (isLoading) return <LoadingSpinner title={title} />;
  if (error)
    return <InvalidStateAPI description={error.message} title={title} />;
  return (
    <>
        <Line data={lineData} />
        <Bar data={barData} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Here's the content of `useData`, which is imported from another file:

```
export function useData(queryId, chartId, setData) {
  return useQuery(
    queryId,
    () =>
      fetchData(chartId, "models").then((resp) => {
        setData(resp.Item.data);
      })
  );
}
```

`fetchData` is a function that queries an AWS DDB table. I'm happy to post that function, but I'm currently excluding it for brevity.

Rendering `Component` results in this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')`. I suspect this error is thrown because a component doesn't get its data in time for rendering. I thought this would be solved by adding `const isLoading = loadingLine && loadingBar;`, as suggested in [this](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/discussions/764) post, but it did not.

Finally, on the recommendation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66427968/how-to-handle-multiple-queries-with-react-query) SO answer, I decided to use `useQueries`. The [documentation](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQueries) is quite sparse, but it recommends the following format:

```
const results = useQueries([
   { queryKey: ['post', 1], queryFn: fetchPost },
   { queryKey: ['post', 2], queryFn: fetchPost },
 ])
```

I modified my original code to the following:

```
 const results = useQueries([
   {
     queryKey: ["post", 1],
     queryFn: useData2("barQuery", "BAR_TEST_SINGLE", setBarData),
   },
   {
     queryKey: ["post", 2],
     queryFn: useData2("lineQuery", "LINE_TEST", setLineData),
   },
 ]);
```

but now I'm getting this error: `TypeError: _this2.options.queryFn is not a function`.

Am I formatting my query incorrectly? How can I fix it? Alternatively, are there other ways to run different queries using `react-query` in the same component?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, this is not the correct syntax for `useQueries`. You can't pass a useQuery hook in as `queryFn` - the `queryFn` needs the function that fetches the data, in your case, that would be `fetchData(chartId, "models")`.

The root cause of your initial problem however seems to be that your condition only waits until *one* of the queries has finished loading:

```
const isLoading = loadingLine && loadingBar;
```

if `loadingLine` is `false` and `loadingBar` is `true`, this condition will yield `false` and you will thus not display a loading spinner anymore. If you want to wait until *all* queries have finished loading, that would be:

```
const isLoading = loadingLine || loadingBar;
```

---

lastly, I'd like to point out that copying data from react-query to local state is not necessary. react-query will return the result returned from the `queryFn` as the `data` field. My implementation would look something like that:

```
export function useData(queryId, chartId) {
  return useQuery(
    [queryId, chartId],
    () => fetchData(chartId, "models")
  );
}

const { error: errorBar, isLoading: loadingBar, data: barData } = useData(
    "barQuery",
    "BAR_TEST_SINGLE",
  );
  const { error: errorLine, isLoading: loadingLine, data: lineData } = useData(
    "lineQuery",
    "LINE_TEST",
  );

  const isLoading = loadingLine || loadingBar;
```

or, alternatively, with `useQueries`:

```
 const results = useQueries([
   {
     queryKey: ["barQuery", "BAR_TEST_SINGLE"],
     queryFn: () => fetchData("BAR_TEST_SINGLE", "models")
   },
   {
     queryKey: ["lineQuery", "LINE_TEST"],
     queryFn: () => fetchData("LINE_TEST", "models")
   },
 ]);

const isLoading = results.some(result => result.isLoading)
```

Comment: When I use `useQueries` I always get a `status` of `loading` and so my `data` is undefined. How do I fix that?

Comment: @vaibhavdeep, I am also facing the same issue. Did you find any solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

@TKDo, Your solution only works with react-query versions till "4.0.0-alpha.1", the issue will crop up again, if we use any latest version of react-query ("4.0.0-alpha.2" and above). To fix that, we need to use an object and assign the list of queries as the value to queries key like below example.

```
const results = useQueries({queries: [
{
  queryKey: ["barQuery", "BAR_TEST_SINGLE"],
  queryFn: () => fetchData("BAR_TEST_SINGLE", "models")
},
{
  queryKey: ["lineQuery", "LINE_TEST"],
  queryFn: () => fetchData("LINE_TEST", "models")
}]});
```

[React-Query V4 Migration docs for reference](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/blob/beta/docs/src/pages/guides/migrating-to-react-query-4.md#new-api-for-usequeries)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't add a comment as my reputation is currently too low, but I had the same problem as vaibhav-deep, so thought I would put this here even if it's a bit off-topic.

It was fixed by returning whatever my data is in the async/await fetch function.

```
const queries = useQueries(
queryList.map((query) => {
  return {
    queryKey: [query],
    queryFn: () => fetchData(query),
  };
})
);

async function fetchData(query) {
  const response = await axios.get(apiCall)... 
  
  ...

  return response.data;
}
```